# Why can't I call methods on unlinked DLL but can do this ? C++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, dll, linker

So I've got DLL Alice and DLL Bob. I cannot call each others methods. But there's one bridge. I can assign a pointer (I'll say **the** pointer from now on) from either DLL and read it in either DLL. 
But if I assign the pointer to be an instance of a class defined in Alice, I cannot call it's methods from Bob and vice versa. I also cannot access it's members. They are simply not linked (I get LNK error). So far so good.

And now, to the question. I've created the same class (just different name - let's call it MirrorClass) in Alice and in Bob. When I assign the pointer (both DLLs can access it) an instance of the MirrorClass created in Alice, I still cannot call it's methods from Bob. But what I can do is **pretend** (explicit casting) it's an instance from Bob's MirrorClass and it'll call Bob's methods defined in Bob's version of MirrorClass and everything still works. Even though it was Alice's instance of MirrorClass. 
Obviously once I change the layout of MirrorClass, it stops working.

How is that even possible ?
I guess it has something to do with virtual addresses maybe, or perhaps every DLL has it's own address space. But then, objects are just pointers, so from my understanding you wouldn't even need linking, so I'm really off with my understanding of this.

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: Why don't you show the code.

Comment: Any DLL can use any other DLL. You just need to include the right definitions and configure the imports correctly.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It's a huge codebase, lots of projects and it's a mess. So I tried to at least simplify it textually.

Comment: @ElderBug Well yes, but I *think* I don't have that. It's not linked, no exports, no "LoadDll" or something, just included headers to know about the class layout.

Comment: If there is no LoadLibrary ("dynamic" DLL), then there has to be imports, even if they are implicit. Usually is it `__declspec( dllimport )` hidden behind a macro. A using B and B using A shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't have interdependent headers. A imports B and B imports A. One of the two will be loaded before but it doesn't matter. When the second is loaded, the first is already loaded and imports can be resolved.

Comment: When you say "I cannot call each others methods", is that a restriction imposed on you, or is it that you couldn't make it work ? Because I can assure you it's possible, and you probably already have all what is needed. Code with DLLs really aren't that different from other codes (it's just a linking difference), so it's no surprise you can make things work with a "mirror" class. It would be the same if you used a mirror class in a single program with no DLL. Nothing is different with DLLs here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer to a class, to use the methods the class vtbl must be defined (for example, using an abstract class (pure virtual functions)).
That is how COM works in Windows, for example.

Now If you got the same interface in both DLLs and the same compiler build, the first vtbl would be the same with the second, which make hard-casting from A* to B* to work.

This is of course UB. It may or it may not work.

The DLLs share the same address space when loaded into the same process, and each one can use any of the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "vtbl would be the same", like it would point to the exact same functions ? 
Also, why would we then need a linker at all if we could just see the class layout from .h and access the pointer ?

Comment: If you have class A with 2 member virtual functions, there is a virtual table for looking up these functions at run time when someone has an A* pointer. If you do that twice for an identical class B, you have two vtbls which may be equal, so casting from A* to B* would work, although it would be very bad.